# swift: can't set authorization header in http request

Tags: swift, http, header, authorization, alamofire

```
    let URL: Foundation.URL = Foundation.URL(string: "MYURL")!
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:URL)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.setValue("8be4967f-dbc4-42f9-982a-30a25d9d5e12", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

As you see both `Content-type` and `Authorization` headers are set,  but when server receives it, there is no Authorization in header.
But if I change `Authorization` word to any other random word, it works fine. (the problem consists even with Alamofire) any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Try to change to setValue("Basic 8be4967f-dbc4-42f9-982a-30a25d9d5e12", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

Comment: thanks but didn't work @OlegGordiichuk